# How to change text of legend in chart column c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

i have a problem with chart column in c# , when i want to change text legend to take the x value , it show me this (#VALX) in the place of legend.

and this is my code in `formLoad()`

```
{
     chart1.DataSource = Remplir("SELECT count(*) AS Expr1, Candidat.Sourcing FROM Sourcing INNER JOIN Candidat ON Sourcing.Sourcing=Candidat.Sourcing GROUP BY Candidat.Sourcing");
     chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Sourcing";
     chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Expr1";
     chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the code we wont be able to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not given your `series` a `Name` and your query doesn't supply one either. So you simply should insert this:

```
chart1.Series[0].Name = "Your Series Title";
```

Obviously you can only display **one** piece of text in a `Legend`, not all X-Values!

If you want to keep the name and set the `Legend` text **independently**, use the 
`Series.LegendText` property:

```
chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "Your Series Legend Text";
```

Comment: _What if there are multiple point per series?_ I don't know what you mean.?? Almost all the time a Series will contain many DataPoints.

Answer (score 0):

`#VALX` is a placeholder (variable) for the x value. It should be replaced automatically with the actual X Value of your series when running your code.

You can use it to display dynamic data in your legend.

Comment: yes that's what i want , display dynamic data in my legend , in pie chart works well ,but with column chart display #VALX in place of value !!!! , i can't find the solution , and thank's for advance (y)

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the binding. Could you add the output type of your Remplir method and check if your query from sql is working as expected?

Comment: @Free_think could you enlarge the image? The resolution is too low to recognize.

Comment: `#VALX` doesn't make sense in a legend - which data point's x value will be displayed? `#VALX` is used for tooltips and labels on `DataPoints`, not legends.